# Why is this putting the int value of the length in that index position and not just adding to it?

Tags: java, arrays, iteration

I am iterating over a file and getting the number of characters in each word. When I find the length of each word it is putting the int value of the amount of characters into that array index position. I can't figure out why or how to solve it. I have then even tried to re-iterate over the array and divide each int by it's index position, but couldn't figure out why I kept getting a / by 0 exception. Below is my code. The txt file I am using has 1 two letter word and 2 three letter words. The output is Frequency of words with 2 characters is 2 (should be 1) and Frequency of words with 3 characters is 6 (should be 2). For this assignment we only need to count the frequency for all words <23 characters and group all above 23 characters into the the last array index position. Below is my code. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
    private final int WORDLENGTH = 23;
    private int[] wordLengthCount = new int [WORDLENGTH];

    while (token.hasMoreTokens()){
            token1 = token.nextToken();
            for (int t = 0; t<token1.length(); t++){
                wordLengthCount[token1.length()-1]++;
                }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This code here

```
token1 = token.nextToken();                    //Getting your token
    for (int t = 0; t<token1.length(); t++)    //For each character in token
    {
        wordLengthCount[token1.length()-1]++;  //Increment count array
    }
```

Is incrementing the count array for the number of characters in your `String token1`. Hence

```
1 * 2 character word = 2
2 * 3 character word = 6
```

You don't need your `for` loop here, just do this in your `while` loop

```
token1 = token.nextToken();              //Get token
wordLengthCount[token1.length()-1]++;    //Increment your count array
```

Comment: Thanks. That makes sense. As I said above I can't believe I didn't see it sooner. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

```
while(token.hasMoreTokens()){
    token1 = token.nextToken();
    wordLengthCount[token1.length()-1]+=1;
}
```

You don't need to to iterate over every character for each token.  Just reference the index in your array referred to by the number of letters in the word you are examining.

So here you'll see for a 3 letter word:

```
wordLengthCount[3 -1] +=1;
//so wordLengthCount[2] = 1 now
```

Or for a 2 letter word:

```
wordLengthCount[2 -1] +=1;
//so wordLengthCount[1] = 1 now.
```

If you want to know the number of characters, you can get them by multiplying the index of the element you are examining by the value of that index like so:

```
//this will give you number of 3 letter word characters in file.
wordLengthCount[2] *= 3;
//or more useful, print out all frequencies and the number of characters in file
//which contributed to frequency
for(int i=0;i<wordLengthCount.length;i++){
    System.out.println("Frequency for "+(i+1)+" letter words = "
        +wordLengthCount[i]+", characters = "+(wordLengthCount[i]*(i+1)));
}
```

Comment: Thank you. That makes complete sense. I can't believe I didn't see it sooner. I was so in the mind set of iterating. Keeping it simple works better. Thanks again.